# How to display selected tab content and hide other tab's content?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the first tab content to be shown by default but the tab's content gets hidden and is displayed only after clicking on that tab.

```js
 function opentabs(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {  
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
     
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
     evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    
  }
  
   function opensubtabs(evt, SubTabName) {
    var i, content, links;
   
    content = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-content");
    for (i = 0; i <content.length; i++) {
        content[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    links = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i <links.length; i++) {
        links[i].className =links[i].className.replace(" clicked", "");
      }
  
 

    document.getElementById(SubTabName).style.display = 'block';

    
   evt.currentTarget.className += " clicked";

}
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
<ul >
  <li class="tablinks active" onclick="opentabs(event, 'Tab1');"><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
  <li class="tablinks" onclick="opentabs(event, 'Tab2')"><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
  <li class="tablinks" onclick="opentabs(event, 'Tab3')"><a href="#">Tab3</a></li>
  <li class="tablinks" onclick="opentabs(event, 'Tab4')"><a href="#">Tab4</a></li>
  <li class="tablinks" onclick="opentabs(event, 'Tab5')"><a href="#">Tab5</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="Tab1" class="tabcontent"  style="display:block;">
        
          <ul>
           <li class="tablinks clicked" onclick="opensubtabs(event, 'SubTab1')"><a href="#" style="width:100px;">Sub1</a></li>
           <li class="tablinks" onclick="opensubtabs(event, 'SubTab2')"><a href="#" style="width:100px;">Sub2</a></li>
           <li class="tablinks" onclick="opensubtabs(event, 'SubTab3')"><a href="#" style="width:100px;">Sub3</a></li>
           <li class="tablinks" onclick="opensubtabs(event, 'SubTab4')"><a href="#" style="width:100px;">Sub4</a></li>
           <li class="tablinks" onclick="opensubtabs(event, 'SubTab5')"><a href="#" style="width:100px;">Security</a></li>
           </ul>
           <div id="SubTab1" class="tab-content"  style="display:block; ">
             <p>This is subtab 1!</p>
           </div>
           <div id="SubTab2" class="tab-content">
           <p>.......</p>
           </div>
           so on... till sub5
           
           
           
           
           <div id="Tab2" class="tabcontent"
          <ul>
           <li class="tablinks clicked"onclick="opensubtabs(event, 'SubTab6')"><a href="#" style="width:100px;">sub6</a></li>
           <li class="tablinks" onclick="opensubtabs(event, 'SubTab7')"><a href="#" style="width:100px;">sub7</a></li>
           <div id="SubTab6" class="tab-content"  style="display: block">
           
              <p>This is sub6 !</p>
               </div>
               <div id="sub7" class="tab-content">
               <p>This is sub7</p>
               <div>
               
               
               
               and so on....
```

I want sub1 and sub6 to be displayed without clicking on it. If you click on other subtabs and go back to sub1 it's not getting displayed unless you click on that tab. Any suggestions please?

Comment: well there are quite alot of ways to do this, you might consider adding class "active" and loop throw all tabs which dosent have this class(at the start).

Comment: Maybe try calling opentabs() for tab1 at onload..

Comment: I tried using a separate class  but didn't work..:'(

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="tablinks clicked"  style="display:block" onclick="opensubtabs(event, 'SubTab1')">
  <a href="#" style="width:100px;">Sub1</a>
</li>
```

Insert `style="display:block"` in the `li tabcontent` which you want to display on page load without click event.